# Couldn't connect internet in xamarin android emulator -AVD_for_Nexus_One_by_Google

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator

I have created simple listview apps using xamarin form and data are coming from webservices.

My current problem is , i couldnt connect internet my android emulator. Please anyone can guide how to do?

[My Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYLbi.jpg)

Notes: My PC connected internet via LAN.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the connection settings of your emulator when you create one try creating one more emulator and revert us so we can help you create one.

The way i suggest you do it is use the emulators that visual studio provides check visual emulators in your respected search menu to find it .

One of the problems could be you do not have internet permissions which you can update in your manifest using this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

If this doesn't work follow the steps below :

1.Go to settings->Wireless & networks->mobile networks->Access Point Names.

2.Press menu button. an option menu will appear.

3.from the option menu select New APN.

4.Click on Name. provide name to apn say My APN.

5.Click on APN. Enter www.

6.Click on Proxy. enter your proxy server IP. you can get it from internet explorers internet options menu.

7.click on Port. enter port number in my case it was 8080. you can get it from internet explorers internet options menu.

8.Click on User-name. provide user-name in format domain\user-name. generally it is your systems login.

9.Click on password. provide your systems password.

10.press menu button again. an option menu will appear.

11.press save. try n run your browser. hope its work for you it worked for me. good luck.

Comment: yes . i have created one more emulator , but still getting same error that net::ERR_TIMED_OUT . Please can you help , what to do in order to connect internet ?

Comment: Well yes but i'm not sure how can you configure one now and i can help you on the fly if you like @Surviva

Comment: After followed above step i m getting error on emulator browser like below. WebPage not available. net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to the Internet from an Android emulator can be tricky.

One common issue is falling foul of a network proxy. If you have one on your network you need to configure it on the emulator.

[Here is an article](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html) detailing Android emulator network settings.